# After I installed flask by pip3, why can't I run it?

Tags: python, flask, pip

After I installed flask by pip3, why can't I run it? How can I run it then? Thanks.

```
$ pip3 install Flask
Collecting Flask
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/e7/08578774ed4536d3242b14dacb4696386634607af824ea997202cd0edb4b/Flask-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Werkzeug>=0.14 (from Flask)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/c4/12e3e56473e52375aa29c4764e70d1b8f3efa6682bef8d0aae04fe335243/Werkzeug-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting click>=5.1 (from Flask)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/37/45185cb5abbc30d7257104c434fe0b07e5a195a6847506c074527aa599ec/Click-7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Jinja2>=2.10 (from Flask)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/ff/ae64bacdfc95f27a016a7bed8e8686763ba4d277a78ca76f32659220a731/Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting itsdangerous>=0.24 (from Flask)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/ae/44b03b253d6fade317f32c24d100b3b35c2239807046a4c953c7b89fa49e/itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2>=2.10->Flask)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/08/04/f2191b50fb7f0712f03f064b71d8b4605190f2178ba02e975a87f7b89a0d/MarkupSafe-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: Werkzeug, click, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, itsdangerous, Flask
Successfully installed Flask-1.0.2 Jinja2-2.10 MarkupSafe-1.1.0 Werkzeug-0.14.1 click-7.0 itsdangerous-1.1.0

$ export FLASK_APP=hello.py

$ python3 flask run
python3: can't open file 'flask': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: the command can be used without python3, for instance in a virtual env. But where is the code, what program are you trying to run? Flask doesn't 'run' just like you just tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try as a module

> python -m flask run

Answer (score 0):

Your command does not run, because `python3` expects a file as its argument, and there's not one there (or a directory, check out the documentation linked below).

The option `-m module-name` will search the `sys.path` for the *module* you pass on, and execute its contents as the `__main__` module. Check out the official [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html).

You might have seen that as an example, where people run `python3 -m http.server` to serve files from their current directory.

Comment: What does `python3` expect if I don't specify `-m`?

Comment: As per the documentation linked above, *it depends*.... When called with a `file name` argument or with a file as standard input, it reads and executes a script from that file. When called with a `directory name` argument, it reads and executes an appropriately named script from that directory. When called with `-c` command, it executes the Python statement(s) given as command. Here command may contain multiple statements separated by newlines. When called with `-m` module-name, the given module is located on the Python module path and executed as a script.